# Kendo Angular 4 Grid doesn't navigate properly within select event

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, grid

I have a simple Kendo Angular 4 grid.

I want to navigate the user to another route when they click a row.

To do so I handle the selection change event and call the navigate method on the router.

But I get **both** the old content (the grid) and the new content (the destination route).

Is this a bug or do I need to do something else?

Answer (score 0):

This had nothing to do with the Kendo grid, there was another completely unrelated issue that was causing the error.